# xlsxwriter module won't open/close Excel file correctly

Tags: python, error-handling, exception, xlsxwriter

I'm writing a program that writes data to an Excel file using the `xlsxwriter` module.

The code that opens the workbook is:

```
excel = xlsxwriter.Workbook('stock.xlsx')
```

This used to work. Then I changed some stuff around in the bottom of the program (waaaaay after that line) and now it doesn't work, saying this:

```
Exception ignored in: <bound method Workbook.__del__ of <xlsxwriter.workbook.Workbook object at 0x02C702B0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line 147, in __del__
    raise Exception("Exception caught in workbook destructor. "
Exception: Exception caught in workbook destructor. Explicit close() may be required for workbook.
```

This has happened when I forget to close the file before running it again (as it is trying to write to a file that's open in Excel which won't work), but I don't even have Excel open and it does this.

How can I fix this? Do I need to restart or something?

Also, I tried to have a `try...except` loop to stop the program if the initialization doesn't work. Even with `except:` only, without a specific exception, it still completes the program unless I kill it manually. The script basically opens the Excel file, spends a long time downloading data from the Internet, and then writing that to the Excel file. I want it to stop if the initialization doesn't work so I don't have to wait for the script to complete (it can take up to 15 minutes). I'm pretty sure that it has something to do with the fact that it says "`Exception ignored`", but I'm not familiar with all the error-fu in Python.

**EDIT:**

I added an `excel.close()` command right at the end and now it doesn't give me the first error, but a second (and much larger and scarier) one:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\carte_000\Python\stock_get_rev8.py", line 161, in <module>
    excel.close()
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line 287, in close
    self._store_workbook()
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line 510, in _store_workbook
    xml_files = packager._create_package()
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\packager.py", line 132, in _create_package
    self._write_worksheet_files()
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\packager.py", line 189, in _write_worksheet_files
    worksheet._assemble_xml_file()
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 3395, in _assemble_xml_file
    self._write_sheet_data()
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 4802, in _write_sheet_data
    self._write_rows()
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 4988, in _write_rows
    self._write_cell(row_num, col_num, col_ref)
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 5148, in _write_cell
    xf_index = cell.format._get_xf_index()
AttributeError: type object 'str' has no attribute '_get_xf_index'
```

**EDIT 2:**

The part of the code that actually *writes* to the file is this:

```
for r, row in enumerate(data):
    for c, cell in enumerate(row):
        if 'percent' in formats[c]:
            sheet.write(r + r_offset, c + c_offset, cell, eval(formats[c].replace('_f', '')))
        elif '_f' in formats[c]:
            sheet.write(r + r_offset, c + c_offset, cell.format(n=str(r + r_offset)), eval(formats[c].replace('_f', '')))
        else:
            sheet.write(r + r_offset, c + c_offset, cell, eval(formats[c][0] + formats[c].replace('_f', '')[-1]))
```

If I replace all the fancy `if...else` stuff with a single

```
sheet.write(r + r_offset, c + c_offset, cell)
```

it doesn't give me the error, and seems to work fine.

This doesn't provide the functionality I need, as some columns need to be formulas whose numbers change based on the row. What in the above code is causing the `excel.close()` line to bug out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my code I was trying to reference a non-existent format. When I called `excel.close()`, that seems to be when it actually writes everything, so if there's an invalid format, it'll throw an error there.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same issue and successfully resolved it

```
AttributeError: type object 'str' has no attribute '_get_xf_index'
```

This error message occurs if to set extra argument to `sheet.write()`
So instead of `sheet.write(row, col, "Some_text", variable)` please use `sheet.write(row, col, "Some_text"+variable)`

...and `excel.close()` if script finished to use excel file

Answer (score 3):

> What in the above code is causing the excel.close() line to bug out?

It crashes at `excel.close()` because it's when the packager is called. The error comes from the fourth argument in the `sheet.write` calls: `eval` isn't returning `xlsxwriter.Format` objects but `str` objects, which haven't got the `_get_xf_index` method and therefore they throw an exception.

You may be able to improve your code avoiding using `eval`, which is almost always a bad practice, mapping your formats in dicts and/or lists or, if the formats are really complex, creating a function that returns the format.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are forgetting to close the file - Once you are done writing data to the file, you will need to close the file handler using

```
excel.close()
```

as mentioned in the [docs here](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/workbook.html).

Comment: See my edit: This just gives me a big error about something being a `str` when it's not supposed to be.

Comment: @spelchekr You will need to add more code to the post to make it understandable and get further help. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve